# Prepend character to loop for items in a nested array - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component

Inside a `v-for` loop I am trying to prepend a character to each item of nested array that can hold several items.

I have tried a few routes but did not succeed:

```
:data-filter="addDot(item.buttonFilters)"

addCharacter(el) {
    for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
        return '.'+el+','
    }
},

=> data-filter=".cat2,cat1,"
```

other approach:

```
:data-filter="'.'+item.buttonFilters"

=> data-filter=".cat1,cat2"
```

desired output:

```
=> data-filter=".cat1,.cat2"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```html
:data-filter="item.buttonFilters.map(el => `.${el}`).join(',')"
```